# The ClassNotFoundException when running a jar from command line

Tags: jar

I am not sure what is missing from this jar file but when I try to run the jar from the command line, it cannot load the main entry point:
This is the directory that contains the classes and the resources for my application.

```
C:\Users\hrh74\Documents\ABack up\NetBeansProjects\mavenfxedittableview\target\classes\org\openjfx\mavenfxedittableview

09/04/2020  08:48 PM    <DIR>          .
09/04/2020  08:48 PM    <DIR>          ..
09/03/2020  04:24 PM             2,502 addressBookData.xml
09/02/2020  05:52 PM             9,562 Address_Book.png
09/02/2020  05:52 PM               859 birthdaystatistic.fxml
09/02/2020  05:52 PM             3,274 BirthdaystatisticController.class
09/02/2020  05:52 PM             3,224 DarkTheme.css
09/02/2020  05:52 PM             2,072 DateUtil.class
09/02/2020  05:52 PM             1,214 LocalDateAdapter.class
09/02/2020  05:52 PM             3,523 Person.class
09/02/2020  05:52 PM             4,535 personeditdialog.fxml
09/02/2020  05:52 PM             5,128 PersoneditdialogController.class
09/02/2020  05:52 PM             1,029 PersonListWrapper.class
09/02/2020  05:52 PM             6,412 personoverview.fxml
09/02/2020  05:52 PM             1,904 rootlayout.fxml
09/02/2020  05:52 PM             4,490 RootlayoutController.class
09/02/2020  05:52 PM             9,060 TableEditApp.class
09/02/2020  05:52 PM             6,812 TableVieweditController.class
              16 File(s)         65,600 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  57,686,331,392 bytes free
```

I created an app.jar for my application and specified the application's main entry class.

```
C:\Users\hrh74\Documents\ABack up\NetBeansProjects\mavenfxedittableview\target
\classes\org\openjfx>jar cvfe app.jar TableEditApp.class -C mavenfxedittableview  .

added manifest
adding: addressBookData.xml(in = 2502) (out= 376)(deflated 84%)
adding: Address_Book.png(in = 9562) (out= 9567)(deflated 0%)
adding: birthdaystatistic.fxml(in = 859) (out= 372)(deflated 56%)
adding: BirthdaystatisticController.class(in = 3274) (out= 1544)(deflated 52%)
adding: DarkTheme.css(in = 3224) (out= 826)(deflated 74%)
adding: DateUtil.class(in = 2072) (out= 941)(deflated 54%)
adding: LocalDateAdapter.class(in = 1214) (out= 537)(deflated 55%)
adding: Person.class(in = 3523) (out= 1277)(deflated 63%)
adding: personeditdialog.fxml(in = 4535) (out= 872)(deflated 80%)
adding: PersoneditdialogController.class(in = 5128) (out= 2418)(deflated 52%)
adding: PersonListWrapper.class(in = 1029) (out= 485)(deflated 52%)
adding: personoverview.fxml(in = 6412) (out= 1149)(deflated 82%)
adding: rootlayout.fxml(in = 1904) (out= 542)(deflated 71%)
adding: RootlayoutController.class(in = 4490) (out= 2097)(deflated 53%)
adding: TableVieweditController.class(in = 6812) (out= 2835)(deflated 58%)
```

The app.jar created successfully. Here is the content of META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 14.0.2 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: TableEditApp.class
```

Here is my classpath having the current directory '.' in the beginning.

```
.;C:\Users\hrh74\Documents\ABack up\NetBeansProjects\javalearning\build\classes;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_251\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\lib;
```

When I list the content of the jar file, all the classes are properly packaged in the jar.

```
C:\Users\hrh74\Documents\ABack up\NetBeansProjects\mavenfxedittableview\target\classes\org\openjfx>jar tvf app.jar
     0 Fri Sep 04 23:22:18 IRDT 2020 META-INF/
    98 Fri Sep 04 23:22:18 IRDT 2020 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
  2502 Thu Sep 03 16:24:22 IRDT 2020 addressBookData.xml
  9562 Wed Sep 02 17:52:36 IRDT 2020 Address_Book.png
   859 Wed Sep 02 17:52:36 IRDT 2020 birthdaystatistic.fxml
  3274 Wed Sep 02 17:52:40 IRDT 2020 BirthdaystatisticController.class
  3224 Wed Sep 02 17:52:36 IRDT 2020 DarkTheme.css
  2072 Wed Sep 02 17:52:40 IRDT 2020 DateUtil.class
  1214 Wed Sep 02 17:52:38 IRDT 2020 LocalDateAdapter.class
  3523 Wed Sep 02 17:52:38 IRDT 2020 Person.class
  4535 Wed Sep 02 17:52:36 IRDT 2020 personeditdialog.fxml
  5128 Wed Sep 02 17:52:40 IRDT 2020 PersoneditdialogController.class
  1029 Wed Sep 02 17:52:40 IRDT 2020 PersonListWrapper.class
  6412 Wed Sep 02 17:52:36 IRDT 2020 personoverview.fxml
  1904 Wed Sep 02 17:52:36 IRDT 2020 rootlayout.fxml
  4490 Wed Sep 02 17:52:38 IRDT 2020 RootlayoutController.class
  9060 Wed Sep 02 17:52:38 IRDT 2020 TableEditApp.class
  6812 Wed Sep 02 17:52:38 IRDT 2020 TableVieweditController.class
```

Finally, when I run the application from the command line using java –jar app.jar, I get the ClassNotFoundException.

```
C:\Users\hrh74\Documents\ABack up\NetBeansProjects\mavenfxedittableview\target\classes\org\openjfx>java -jar app.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class TableEditApp.class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TableEditApp.class
```

I tried to adhere to the spec to the best of my knowledge, so I am not sure why this is not working. Any idea, what might be causing this exception?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @-a_horse_with_no_name: I removed the screenshots. I hope this is better.

Comment: Is there any mixup in naming? I see you are specifying `TableEditApp` in your command but in the manifest and the error message it is `EditTableApp`.

Comment: @takendarkk: hmmmm.... good question, let me look into it and report back. Thank you.

Comment: @takendarkk: I corrected the naming mixup and now it is TableEditApp. However, the problem persists. In fact, I tried to write a simple HelloWorld.java then packaged it in the Hello.jar with the main class pointing to org.me.HelloWorld and put the Hello.jar in the classpath but the same ClassNotFoundException persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered something interesting in respect to the HelloWorld.java that I mentioned in my last comment. I abandoned using the "jar cvfe" and instead created a file name mymanifest.txt and placed the name of the class with the main entry as "Main-Class: org.me.HelloWorld" followed by two blank lines (per specification). I packaged the jar using the "jar cvmf" instead of "jar cvfe" and it WORKED FINE. I then applied the same method to my application jar creation, and now I am getting a Linkage Error instead of ClassNotFoundException. Perhaps, it has something to do with the JavaFX library that I have to investigate deeper. In summary, I suspect that the "jar cvfe" switch might not be working as described in the Java tutorial. I have had found errors in the tutorial in the past and this MIGHT be another one.

Anyway, thank you all for your comments.